# Selenium Geckodriver, how to check for visible text on a page?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver

I was attempting to use

```
driver.find_element_by_visible_text("text")
```

but it stated that geckodriver had no attribute visible_text does anyone know the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As per the *Selenium-Python* documentation of the [**Locator Strategies**](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) the following *Locator Strategy* is not a valid one. Instead you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies* :

- Using `text()` attribute :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='the_desired_text']")
  ```
- Using `contains()` :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(.,'the_desired_text')]")
  ```
- Using `normalize-space()` :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[normalize-space()='the_desired_text']")
  ```

Comment: alright thanks I'll give it a try are you 100% sure this will work?